# How can I add a custom package in a pyramid project?

Tags: python, pyramid

I created a pyramid project (with `pcreate -s starter projtest`) and with the default structure, pserve runs the project as expected.
But, when I add a package directory (for example, called "skimpygimpy") in the same level of `views.py` and `templates` directory, pserve isn't able to launch the project (`invalid command name 'development.ini'` error).

```
projtest/
 |-- CHANGES.txt
 |-- development.ini
 |-- MANIFEST.in
 |-- myproject
 |   |-- __init__.py
 |   |-- skimpygimpy
 |   |   |-- __init__.py
 |   |   |-- file.py
 |   |   |--  ...
 |   |-- static
 |   |   |-- favicon.ico
 |   |   |-- logo.png
 |   |   |-- pylons.css
 |   |-- templates
 |   |   |-- mytemplate.pt
 |   |-- tests.py
 |   |-- views.py
 |-- production.ini
 |-- README.txt
 |-- setup.cfg
 |-- setup.py
```

So, how could I add a custom package inside a pyramid project and avoid this error (invalid command name 'development.ini') when I call pserve?

More informations about the problem:

I did these commands:

```
mkdir pyramid
cd pyramid/
virtualenv --no-site-packages env
cd env/
bin/easy_install pyramid
bin/pcreate -s starter projtest
cd projtest
cd projtest
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/skimpygimpy/
cd skimpygimpy
touch __init__.py
cd ..
cd ..
../bin/python setup.py develop
../bin/pserve development.ini
```

And, then, the message:
`invalid command name 'development.ini'`

If I delete the "skimpygimpy" directory, and rerun

```
../bin/python setup.py develop
../bin/pserve development.ini
```

It's OK.

The development.ini file:
http://codepad.org/VKPXm0jf

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you are just invoking pserve improperly, but I wouldn't know because you didn't show it.

Comment: Hi @MichaelMerickel! When I remove the "skimpygimpy" directory, the pserve launches the project. However, when I re-add this directory, pserve shows the error. Just it.

Is allowed a custom directory in a pyramid scaffold? Is necessary any configuration line inside development.ini or setup.py?

Comment: What is the exact pserve command line you're executing, and from which folder path are you executing it from?

Comment: @LeonardoAndrade there are no such limitations. You need to show the command you are executing and the full error message, and possibly your ini file. There is not enough info here to diagnose.

Comment: Hi, @MichaelMerickel. I edited the question and added more informations about my problem. What am I doing wrong? I'm new with pyramid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a weird one, I'm mostly drawing a blank right now but I have a guess. I *think* that since you are cloning skimpygimpy's entire source tree as a subpackage in your project, the skimpygimpy setup.py is being executed inadvertently by something like a `config.scan()` which imports all of the code from the subpackages. When the setup.py gets imported, bad things will happen because it'll use `sys.args` to grab parameters, which would explain why its acting like you called `python setup.py development.ini`.

Dependencies should be found by having them all installed into the same virtualenv, their actual location on the filesystem is not nearly as relevant when this is done because the interpreter's path always includes things in the virtualenv.

As a result, third-party projects should not be placed inside your package but rather installed into the virtualenv, so I think you should avoid placing skimpygimpy as a subpackage at all. This means cloning it int the top-level projtest folder if you like, but not inside the projtest package.

I'm pretty sure your problem would not occur with any manually created packages that didn't include a setup.py. For example `mkdir foo; touch foo/__init__.py` should not exhibit your problem.